# Sending data from a server to a client?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, serversocket

I have problem in this code that client could send message to server but it doesn't receive the message sent from server I've debugged the server code it does everything as well as it should be but client sided it does all the code until message=br.readLine() , it sticks on there

server code

```
    package server; 
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.EOFException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    public class server {
    static Socket s;
    static ServerSocket ss;
    static InputStreamReader isr;
    static BufferedReader br;
    static String message;
    static PrintWriter pw;
    public server(){
try {
    ss=new ServerSocket(8080);
    while(true){
        s=ss.accept();
        isr=new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        message=br.readLine();
        System.out.println(message);
        pw=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
        pw.write("returned back from server to client");
        System.out.println("message sent");
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        isr.close();
        s.close();
    }
} catch (EOFException eofException) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    eofException.printStackTrace();
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 }
    public static void main(String[]args){
server s=new server();
  }
  }
```

client code

```
    package com.example.myapplication;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.Socket;

    public class ClientSender extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {
Socket s;
DataOutputStream dos;
InputStreamReader isr;
BufferedReader br;
PrintWriter pw;
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {
    String message = voids[0];
    try {
        System.out.println("1");

        s = new Socket("0.0.0.0", 8080);
        pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        pw.write(message);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        s.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        System.out.println("2");
        s = new Socket("0.0.0.0", 8080);
        System.out.println("connected to the server");
        isr = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("3");
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        System.out.println("4");
        message = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(message);
        isr.close();
        s.close();
        System.out.println("5");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as sending data from a `ServerSocket`. Your problem here is simply that you are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Add a line terminator to each sent message.

Comment: Ok , i got your idea thanks. but i don't know how to do that can you explain?

Comment: You don't know how to add a line terminator to a message? Have you considered consulting the Javadoc for `PrintWriter`?

Comment: Uh..What?  @user207421suggests just appending a line terminator...

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) instead of writting your own socket client. It's a well-tested and well-documented lib. This will make your life pretty much easier.

Comment: But if he merely repeats the same error he is making here he will just have wasted a week. Not an answer.